# An application of integration by parts in Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in H^2([0, 1])$ with $u(0) = u'(1) = 0$. Is the following calculus correct?
$$\underset{0}{\overset{1}{\int}} u''(x) u(x) dx = u'(x) u(x) \underset{0}{\overset{1}{|}} - \underset{0}{\overset{1}{\int}} u'(x) u'(x) dx = - \underset{0}{\overset{1}{\int}} \frac{(u'(x)^3)'}{3} dx = 0. $$

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't $(u'^3)'$ have a $u''$ term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only correct for $u''=0$, since
$$
-\frac13\int_0^1 (u'(x)^3)' dx = -\int_0^1 u'(x)^2 u''(x)dx,
$$
the latter integral is not equal to $\int_0^1 u''(x)u(x)dx$ (except for special cases $u=0$ or $u''=1$), while the first integral is not zero in general.